# Installing Mailkit and setting up IEmailSender

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm new to ASP Boilerplate and so far it's great.  I'm a little confused on integrating email usage into my existing app.

the documentation for ASP Boilerplate says that the asp.net core version of the boilerplate does not include Mailkit but I'm not able to determine that.

The last thing i'm having an issue with is injecting and using the mail function.  If anyone could share an example or provide a high level view of how this works it would be very appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Comment: ASP.NET Boilerplate already implements `IEmailSender` with MailKit integration. Just inject and use it. Read the documentation: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Email-Sending

Comment: I did read the documentation and it says that asp.net core does not include it. Also the implementation wasn’t 100% clear.

Comment: which version of ABP do you use? I mean ASP.Net Core or MVC! Abp zero-project already implements Mailkit, you just need to follow the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @FaishalAhammad, I figured out how to inject and use it now.  I'm going to follow up on my question a bit later for anyone else that runs into my issue will know how to fix it.